# Left align a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are the three different cases for it. Light grays shows the borders of the collection view and dark gray is for cells.
I have set min spacing and section insets to 0. But still I am getting these unwanted insets, and it seems it only happens when there are more than 1 cell.

I calculate the item sizes like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    guard let item = place?.publicTransports?[indexPath.row] else {
        return CGSize.zero
    }

    var lines = ""
    for (i, line) in item.lines.enumerate() {
        lines.appendContentsOf(line)
        if i != item.lines.count - 1 {
            lines.appendContentsOf(", ")
        }
    }

    let linesString = lines as NSString
    return CGSize(width: linesString.sizeWithAttributes(nil).width + 35 + 20, height: collectionView.bounds.height/2)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying you want the top cell "M2" to left align? the example is the correct result for the collectionview when going over 2 lines.

Comment: I want the cells to stick to their left no matter what. I don't want them to have any insets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the question should read, left align a UICollectionView.

The simplest solution is to go to:

https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

And subclass your layout to this, this will ensure your UICollectionView left aligns, you should set all your insets to 0 first then begin changing them according to your design.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks..